# Dismiss iPhone keyboard triggered by a UITextField in a Subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

My **`ViewController`** contains a **subview**:

The **sub `UIView`** is located in **`NameSubViewController` (class with XIB)**.

Subview contains a **`UITextField`**.

---

I added this action:

**`- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender;`**

in the **`NameSubViewController`** class and connected it to the textfield (did end on exit) from Files Owner in XIB.

But log gives me an error message when I hit return, and nothing happens in simulator.

This is the relevant code:

---

**ViewController.h:**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *nameSubView;
```

**ViewController.m (viewDidLoad):**

```
UIViewController *nameController = [[NameSubViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NameSubViewController" bundle:nil];
nameSubView = [nameController view];

[self.view addSubview:nameSubView];
```

---

**NameSubViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NameSubViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender;
//Not working.. Connected from files owner to textField with option didEndOnExit
```

**NameSubViewController.m:**

```
-(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender
{
[sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

---

**When I hit return I get this message in the log:**

`AppName[6656:f803] -[CALayer textFieldReturn:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e99d40
2012-08-28 02:51:26.954 AppName[6656:f803] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:shouldInsertText:replacingDOMRange:givenAction: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> -[CALayer textFieldReturn:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e99d40`

**and keyboard is not dismissed. What could cause my issue?**

The ViewController:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/80427098@N07/7877111708/in/photostream

The NameSubViewController, view which is displayed in the subView of ViewController:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/80427098@N07/7877111596/in/photostream

Comment: If I add the `IBAction` in the `MainViewController` class I cannot connect it to the text field when text field is in another class..

Comment: What code do you have in the text field IBAction?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you could connect an IBOutlet to an IBAction in another class. And I doubt you can use a xib for a *sub*view. If you want a subview that covers only part of the screen, I'd either put it in the regular xib or add it programmatically (which you can do in combination with a xib). If your subview covers the entire screen, you're probably better off assigning it to a separate view controller and having your MainViewController present that controller. I could be wrong, but if nobody chimes in to the contrary, that's what I would do.

Comment: @Wienke I think you misunderstood.. I have a regular xib for the subview, with a textField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you intending the delegate to be a CALayer?
[CALayer textFieldReturn:]

Right now, it is.

Comment: I have no idea why it is.. Any clue??

Comment: That's what you have it set to. :-)

Comment: Where could I have set the delegate to a CALayer? Never done anything like that. Have I done something wrong in IB with the connections, or or have I done something wrong when I'm trying to dismiss the keyboard from the subview class? I have no more code could be causing that..

Comment: You have either done it in XCode (interface builder) or with code. If what you're saying in the description is right, the "File's Owner" is a CALayer. How are you loading the xib?

Comment: The XIB's `UIView` with the textfieldReturn action is populating the nameSubView property in ViewController

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself at last. It was really simple, I just had to create a class for the NameSubViewController's `UIView` and put the textfieldReturn code in the UIView class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NameSubView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender;

@end
```

And keyboard is returning as it should! Makes sense because only the **UIView** is loaded as subview of the main view, without the subviews view controller. A ViewController should never be a subview of another view, only its view should, so code must be written in the subviews UIView class. not the subviews UIViewController class!